# keep code with figure in knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr, rnw

Is there a way to keep the code and the figure together in `knitr` when using a `figure` environment in LaTeX?

This style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
writing
<<cars, fig.cap="this is a figure.">>=
with(mtcars, plot(mpg, disp))
@
writing
\end{document}
```

will result in the figure being in a float in LaTeX -- which is what I want, except that the figure can [float away from the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991735/latex-figure-label-from-r-plot-using-knitr).

My current workaround is writing the figure environment in LaTeX manually:

```
\begin{figure}
<<cars2>>=
with(mtcars, plot(mpg, disp))
@
\caption{this is a figure.}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a more elegant way that I can do this in `knitr`? Adding the `fig.pos='h'` option is not enough. [`fig.show='asis'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328890/how-to-keep-r-code-and-figure-on-the-same-page-in-rmarkdown-when-producing-a-pdf) also does not get it done.

Do I have to write my own hook? Can this be [done easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657216/caption-above-figure-using-knitr)?

Comment: I guess the manual figure environment is the best way to go.